# BeautifulSoup/Scraping- Python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code that directs me to a website and prints all the titles, dates and times for each session.

However, if you click on each session on the website, there are a list of sub-sessions that drop down.

I want to print each title of the sub-session.

Here is the code I have

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
session=[]

driver.get('https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=20&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page=1')
time.sleep(3)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='accordin_title')
for item in productlist:
    title=item.find('h4').text.strip()
    tim=item.find('span',class_='info_red').text.strip()
    dat=item.find('span',class_='info_blue').text.strip()
    dictionary={"Title":title,"Time":tim,"Date":dat}
    session.append(dictionary)
print(session)
```

Comment: so the `sub_accordin_presentation` has the details but is activated when you click on the plus sign which has the class `sign`. You need to find all the class and use selenium to click on all of them, then get the page html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to get the required content.

To get session title along with their sub-session titles:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=20&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page=1'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#accordin .accordin_details"):
        session_title = items.find_previous(class_="accordin_title").h4.get_text(strip=True)
        subsession_titles = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select(".accordin_list h4")]
        print(session_title,subsession_titles)
```

To get only the sub-session titles:

```
for item in soup.select("#accordin .accordin_details .accordin_list h4"):
    print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```